# Read from a mysql table with multiple threads

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading

I am developing a c# application which needs to read massively from a mysql table. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT ID3 FROM A INNER JOIN B
USING (ID1)
INNER JOIN C
USING (ID2)
INNER JOIN D
USING (ID3)
WHERE ID3 > @Start AND ID3 <= @End
GROUP BY ID3
HAVING SOME CONDITION
```

Since the table is huge I try to create 20 threads, each of them executing a query which replaces

`WHERE ID3 > @Start AND ID3 <= @End`

with

`WHERE ID3 % 20 = i AND ID3 > @Start AND ID3 <= @End`.

However, running this multi-threaded application doesn't cause the program to be any faster. I did some profiling and find that these threads are idle most of time, so I guess there is a certain lock imposed on the mysql tables which prevents more than one thread from accessing them.

I also tried "dirty read", which encloses my query with the following statements:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
...
COMMIT;
```

However, it doesn't seem to bring any acceleration.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

To gain performance, You need to do more than creating additional threads.

1. Check your MySQL is configured to take advantage of multi core processors. MySQL 5.5 and above can be configured to make use of multiple cores
2. Consider [Partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-overview.html) your tables across multiple physical disks.
3. Make available more RAM to your database. For example, if using `innodb`, increase `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to as much as you can afford to. [Here is a writeup on that](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/03/choosing-innodb_buffer_pool_size/)

and this list is not complete.